# Failed installation of lxml module using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, lxml

This error has been reported in previous stack overflow questions, but I have tried everything in the previous questions and it is not working.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Python 2.7 in Enthought Canopy.

After trying pip install lxml or easy_install lxml, my error is as follows:

```
fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory  #include
"libxml/xmlversion.h"
                            ^ compilation terminated. error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

According to previous solutions, I'm supposed to run

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
```

I have run all of these. And they are all showing as already installed.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on debian, not ubuntu, but for basic libraries that should be the same:

```
 % dpkg -S /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h
libxml2-dev: /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h
```

so it's definitely in `libxml2-dev`. Though, are you having `xml2-config` utility in your path when you're doing the pip install? Does the following return the same?

```
 % xml2-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/libxml2
```

ok so it works:

```
 $ xml2-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/libxml2
```

now, can you do:

```
 % ls -l /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h || ls -l /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7747 Oct 13  2013 /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h
```

if the directory or the file is missing, you may need to reinstall `libxml2-dev`:

```
 # apt-get install --reinstall libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Is this what you were asking?

gronke@nomad:~/Downloads$  % xml2-config --cflags
bash: fg: %: no such job
gronke@nomad:~/Downloads$ -I/usr/include/libxml2
bash: -I/usr/include/libxml2: No such file or directory

Comment: ahah, `%` is the prompt :-)

Comment: It says it's there, sorry

Comment: well, it's not a solution for the compilation problem, but you can install `python-lxml` and/or `python3-lxml`.

Comment: if you still want to make it compiled, can you try `pip install -v lxml` and paste the log of the failed install on some pastebin?